# Slowing down the speed of the View Pager in android

Tags: android, performance, animation, android-viewpager, swipe

I wanted to stop the normal swipe effect of the ViewPager so I achieved it with CustomViewPager class....  But I want to show my other fragment in the pager with the title bar click on the first fragment with the same slide animation of the pager...  How can I slow down the slide speed of the pager